# Does the symmetric algebra functor preserve inclusions?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, functoriality

**Theorem:** For any compact abelian group $G$, the homogeneous component $%
H^{2}\left( B_{G};%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
\right) $ of degree $2$ is naturally isomorphic to the character group $%
\widehat{G}$. If $G$ is connected, then the entire cohomology algebra $%
H^{\ast }\left( B_{G};%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
\right) $ is the symmetric $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
$-algebra $P\left( \widehat{G}\right) $ generated by this component of
homogeneous degree $2$.

**Observation:** If $G$ is a compact connected abelian group and $N$ any closed
normal subgroup, then the quotient morphism $q:G\longrightarrow G/N$ induces
an injection $\widehat{q}:\widehat{G/N}\cong N^{\bot }\longrightarrow 
\widehat{G}$ by Pontryagin Duality with annihilator $N^{\bot }$ of $N$ in $%
\widehat{G}$.

Someone says that the symmetric algebra functor $P$ preserves inclusions, we
have $P\left( N^{\bot }\right) \subset P\left( \widehat{G}\right) $, and so $%
H^{\ast }\left( q;%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
\right) :H^{\ast }\left( B_{G/N};%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
\right) \longrightarrow H^{\ast }\left( B_{G};%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
\right) $ is injective.

Another person says that is not true that the symmetric algebra functor $P$
preserves inclusions.

Which one of these is correct? That is  does the symmetric algebra functor $P
$ preserve inclusions?

**Edit**

[image]

I found this note in an article:
[image]

Comment: It is classical that the symmetric algebra functor, as a functor from $R$-modules to commutative $R$-algebras, does not preserve inclusions. But it seems that this is not the symmetric algebra functor that you have in mind. Instead, I think you intend $P$ to be a functor from compact topological abelian groups to commutative rings, sending a group $G$ to the symmetric algebra on the character group of $G$. Is that right? More generally, can you clarify what you intend the domain of your functor $P$ to be?

Comment: @user509184 I saw this symmetric algebra in K. H. Hofmann, P. S. Moster's ''Cohomology Theories for Compact Abelian Groups''. I didn't see any information about this in this book. There is a statement somewhere like this: $P \widehat{G}$ is the symmetric algebra generated by $\widehat{G}$ in degree 2.

Comment: What do you intend the domain of the functor $P$ to be?

Comment: @user509184 https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=kB34CAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA2&hl=tr&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @user509184 Is the character groups of compact abelian groups?

Comment: @user509184 Moreover, Proposition  4 in the article https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1968-74-05/S0002-9904-1968-12108-1/S0002-9904-1968-12108-1.pdf

Comment: I think you are asking about the symmetric algebra functor from $R$-modules to commutative $R$-algebras, particularly in the case $R = Z$. A standard reference for formal properties of this functor is section 6.2 in chapter III of Bourbaki's "Algebra I." Exercise 1 for that section asks the reader to find an example of an injective $R$-module homomorphism whose induced map on symmetric $R$-algebras is not one-to-one. I remember thinking through this material and finding that examples were relatively plentiful when $R$ has Krull dimension $>1$. I do not remember what happens in the case $R=Z$.

Comment: @user509184 Even in the case R=Z, the symmetric algebra functor doesn't preserve the inclusion.   This is because the tensor product doesn't preserve the inclusion, for example we have $Z/p \subset Q/Z$ but $Z/p \otimes _Z Z/p=Z/p$ (on which the action of the symmetric group is trivial), but $Q/Z\otimes Q/Z=0$.

However, the character groups are free, so in this case you get the injection

Comment: @user43326 The character groups of compact connected abelian Lie groups is free. It is generally not true. However, the character groups of connected abelian groups is torsion-free.